# Bash script - permission denied

Tags: linux, bash

I am fairly new to Linux admin work and I have a problem that I cannot figure out.  It may be a simple answer or a newbie question.  I tried searching on here and other places but I cannot find an answer.

I am on trying to run a bash script on a server that I ssh to.  We have a jump host that we login to then we have to ssh to other servers to get access to them - we cannot directly connect to these servers.  My home directory is a network share so it is available on both the jump host and the remote host.

I am able to run the script from my home directory fine on the jump host but when I ssh to the remote host and run it from my home directory on that server I get a permission denied.  I double checked the bash is the same, the network share is the same address host, the permissions look correct.  Is there anything else I can check?  The command I'm trying to run is:

Run this way: sudo bash MY_SCRIPT_NAME

ERROR: bash: MY_SCRIPT_NAME : Permission denied

I don't think the contents of the script matters or what it is running since I can't even get that far.  Again this may be a newbie question.

Comment: What are the success/fail results if you ssh to the remote host and type `cat MY_SCRIPT_NAME` vs. `sudo cat MY_SCRIPT_NAME` ?  Does the script file scroll up your terminal window for both commands, or only for one of them?

Comment: One other thing is to check mount options. In hardened shared environments (or  server installations) locations like `/home` and `/tmp` are often mounted `noexec`.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Would /etc/security/access.conf be impacting your access to execute locally vs remotely ?